# trying to embed audio in html for android

Tags: android, html, audio

I have a web  page, and I want music to play automatically, in a loop from a hidden source. I tried the audio and video tags, but that evidently isn’t supported yet.  So I then I tried  the embed tag, which will play the song, but I cant seem to have it happen in a loop, or automatically when the page is loaded. This embed tag is in the body of my html file:

```
<embed  src="hereiam.mp3"  AUTOSTART=TRUE LOOP=TRUE hidden=TRUE>
```

what can I do to get this song playing on android devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much you can do about audio since support has just been realsed for the latest versions or the android browser. Check this resource for more details about browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20audio%20api

I would suggest you look into javascript libraries such as http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

Quoting from the audiojs site about browser support:

> Mobile Safari (iOS 3+) Android (2.2+, w/Flash) Safari (4+) Chrome (7+)
>   Firefox (3+, w/ Flash) Opera (10+, w/ Flash) IE (6, 7, 8, w/ Flash)

Answer (score 0):

html5 works on the android Chrome browser

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

Hope that helps!

Comment: btw, autoplay, loop, and preload all work in this tag :)